# JAVA: Can interface have non abstarct methods?

Tags: java

I was browsing through Oracle docs, when i came across this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

From what I knew, Interfaces in JAVA can have only abstract methods, but after reading this article I realized I was wrong. Can someone explain me the implications of using non abstract methods in Interfaces?

EDIT:
In JAVA 1.6 , follwoing gives error:

```
public interface NonAbstractMethods {

    void testNonAbstract(){

    }
}
```

Error Message: Abstract methods do not specify a body

Comment: Your link is not working

Comment: @RedAlert I understand that somewhere down the inheritance tree, concrete implementation needs to be provided. But in the link, under the heading "Interface Methods" the concrete implementation is provided within interface itself.

Comment: @Akshay It's a Java 8 feature.

Comment: In java 8, interfaces can have default, static and abstract methods.http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-default-methods/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default methods in interface are only introduced in java 8. Basically it gives you default implementation if the implementing class did not override it.

This also adds the benefit where if you refactor the interface and introduced a new method, it won't break existing implementing classes.

Comment: Ohh! That is the reason , i got an error in JAVA 1.6. Seems like more flexibilty has been added to reduce the work of the programmer. Now, the programmer will need to override only those methods that he requires rather than having to override all the abstract methods.

Answer (score 3):

Java 8 introduced the concept of default methods in interfaces. This would be the closest I know from what you are describing.

Here is the doc for default methods : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

It is basically a default behavior for the classes inheriting the interface.

Edit : As gerrytan pointed out, it also allows you to add methods in your interface without breaking the classes that already implement it.

Answer (score 1):

The interface method specified in the example is a default interface method, a feature introduced in Java 8.
A default method allows the developer to add new methods to an interface without  breaking the existing implementation of the interface.
Read more here, 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Answer (score -2):

Methods in interface are public and abstract by default. Abstract methods don't have an implementation. Only static methods with implementation are allowed in interface all other methods should be public and abstract by default.Method u wrote is not abstract as it is having implementation and neither is it static so it is showing Abstract method don't specify a body error.

Note: A static method in interface must have implementation.

```
public interface NonAbstractMethods {
   static void testNonAbstract(){
}
}
```

This code will not show error.

Comment: `default` methods in an interface can have a body.